# RecyclerView getDecoratedMeasuredWidth is 0

Tags: java, android

I'm actually using `FixedGridLayoutManager`. You can find it here: [LINK](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java)

My RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:splitMotionEvents="false" />
```

The FixedGridLayoutManager works well above API 16.
But I got an error message on API 16.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
    at com.example.test.util.FixedGridLayoutManager.updateWindowSizing(FixedGridLayoutManager.java:313)
    at com.example.test.util.FixedGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(FixedGridLayoutManager.java:172)
```

The `mDecoratedChildWidth` is 0;

Line 165:

```
mDecoratedChildWidth = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(scrap); // 0 
mDecoratedChildHeight = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(scrap);
```

I found a library (android-timetable-core) there I found this `FixedGridLayoutManager` too. This app supports API 16.

Why It's was 0 with API 16?

Anyone have idea?

UPDATE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my adapter's layout item. When `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, then throws the error.

Comment: You are probably retrieving this value before the recyclerview renders it's childs, therefore, it will return always 0.

Comment: It happens when I add the adapter to recycled view.